# System.NotSupportedException occuring

Tags: c#

I have this path which saves a excel sheet on the basis of date and time.
It is Showing 
`System.NotSupportedException`

What is the correct Format ?

```
   string strpath = Server.MapPath("~/SavedFolder/"+ username+ "/"+DateTime.Now+".xlsx/");
```

Comment: If it is not a typo it is probably the automatic conversion of DateTime.Now to a string that produces an invalid name. What is the final value of the string passed to MapPath? For example colon, slash and backslash are invalid in a filename.

Comment: Try to use `DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy")`

Comment: i need to create a file of xlsx based on datetime inside this folder whose path is  Server.MapPath("~/SavedFolder/" +username);

Comment: i removed / from end still same exception

Comment: `DateTime.Now` returns data in `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM` format, but a valid file path cannot contain `:`s.

Comment: What is actual `strpath` value?

Comment: You need to add the stack trace of the exception. It may not be the file name that causes the exception. You can try to save to a fixed path (string strpath = Server.MapPath("~/SavedFolder/dummy.xlsx") ) to see if the file name is the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem (after removing the final slash) is caused by the conversion of DateTime.Now to a string using your locale settings. This produces a string like this

```
 h:\temp\08/06/2016 09:19:42.txt
```

and this string contains invalid chars as you can see calling `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars` (the slash, backslash are confused as part of a folder name, while the colon is simply not a valid char for a file)

You can use the formatting capabilities of NET to prepare your file name in this way

```
filename= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
string strpath = Server.MapPath("~/SavedFolder/"+ username+ "/"+ filename + ".xlsx");
```

Usually, when I need to tag my files with a datetime part, I put the date parts in the order of year, month, day, hour, minute, second to get an easy way to see them sorted in any file explorer that supports ordering by name.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of DateTime.Now.ToString() (which been called in this case), it seems that it contains characters which is not allowed path of file name.

```
string strpath = Server.MapPath("~/SavedFolder/"+ username+ "/"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") +".xlsx");
```